# Tensor product representation of $SU(4)$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, group-theory, representation-theory

Consider the group $SU(4)$ and two of its irreducible representations: the adjoint and the fundamental. I want to take the tensor product of such representations and decompose it into irreps of $SU(4)$, how should I proceed?

Comment: Have you tried the young tableaux?

Comment: If all you care about is the result and not the algorithms for getting it, you can look it up in Yamatsu’s 11232-page (!!) paper “[Finite-Dimensional Lie Algebras and Their Representations for Unified Model Building](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.08771v2)” (an update of [Slansky’s classic paper](https://cds.cern.ch/record/194212/files/198902285.pdf)) or you can compute it with a computer algebra program, such as the [LieART](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.6379) package for *Mathematica*.

Comment: Can you work out 4x15=36+20+4 ?

Comment: If not, read [this](http://www.physics.mcgill.ca/~keshav/673IV/youngtableaux.pdf) to learn the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Using [Young diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau) the tensor decomposition ${\bf 15}\otimes{\bf 4}\cong{\bf 36}\oplus{\bf 20}\oplus{\bf 4}$ amounts to

$$\begin{array}{rl} [~~]&[~~]\cr [~~]\cr [~~] \end{array}
\quad\otimes\quad[a]
\quad\cong\quad
\begin{array}{rl} [~~]&[~~]&[a]\cr [~~]\cr [~~] \end{array}
\quad\oplus\quad
\begin{array}{rl} [~~]&[~~]\cr [~~]&[a]\cr [~~] \end{array}
\quad\oplus\quad
\begin{array}{rl} [~~]&[~~]\cr [~~]\cr [~~]\cr[a] \end{array} $$

References:

1. H. Georgi, *Lie Algebras in Particle Physics,* 1999, Section 13.2.
2. J.J. Sakurai, *Modern Quantum Mechanics,* 1994, Section 6.5.